# GA Management API - Custom Dimensions list() - Error 403: Insufficient Permission

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I'm using Management API (using PY Client Library) to get list of Custom Dimensions as described here -  [Custom Dimensions: list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions/list)

```
link = analytics.management().customDimensions().list(accountId = ACCOUNT_ID, 
                                                     webPropertyId = PROPERTY_ID)
dimensions = link.execute()
```

but the API keeps returning `Error Code: 403, Insufficient Permission`

I'm pretty sure the service account email address I'm using to build credentials object has sufficient Edit, Read & Analyse level access at the GA Account Level!.

I confirm - `get()` and `patch()` verbs execute properly using same credentials, same account, property ID. Even the API Explorer works fine.

Any clue what I might be missing, or potential bug in API ?

Thanks for any clue

Comment: Hi, Still waiting community / google Engg. feedback pls.. I'm a bit unsure whether something wrong I'm doing or some intermittent bug here... Cheers! :)

Comment: Somethings up with your authentication or the accountid, web property id you are supplying if get works list should also work.   Check for a typo then check https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/service-accounts

Comment: my bad - I was using SCOPE `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit` presuming it automatically includes `analytics.readonly` as well.. seems I've to explicitly include `analytics.readonly` and it works now... thanks a look for looking into it. Cheers! :)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that analytics.edit doesn't include analytics.readonly?

Comment: It should.. isn't it ? that's what I thought as well.. but now I'm explicitly  using `analytics.readonly` and it works. changed to `analytics.edit` and again gives `{"code":403,"message":"Insufficient Permission"}`

Comment: I just sent off an email to Google.   I think its weird.  I will let you know if i hear anything back.

Comment: @VibhorJain I am currently going through this issue now. I switched the scope but do you only need to place analytics.readonly or do you need to also place https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics?

Comment: This is the scopes I used: **SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit']**

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem, notice that listing custom dimensions can only be done using those scopes:

['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics']

get() and patch() can be done using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit scope, I am assuming this is the one that you are using.

It is annoying as edit scope can list most of the assets such as goals but not custom dimensions and metrics.

Hope that resolves your problem