# User Deletion API: userDeletionRequests:upsert :: deletionRequestTime field

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Can someone give little clarification how to interpret following parameter:

> deletionRequestTime: datetime`:
>
> This marks the point in time up to which all user data for the specified end user and Google Analytics property or Firebase project should be deleted.`

If I set it to 1st Jan2018 (GTM), does it delete all user data:

- from that date till today (which is how I interpret).. meaning all 2018 data will be gone?
- or, (from epoch time) till that date ... meaning all 2016/2017 etc. data is gone and all that remains is 2018 data?

When trying the API > refreshed User Explorer report in GA interface > I notice all-time data seems is gone (giving me impression that this filed is not respected?). But let me wait 72hrs since API request to draw any conclusion..

Thanks for any clarification.

Cheers!

Comment: can you give me the link to the page you got that quote from?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/userdeletion/v3/reference/userDeletion/userDeletionRequest (or perhaps I'm mis-interpreting, it's not required parameter in the request.. and by default ALL user data up until API request time.. and it's return in only in response for logging purposes?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can set the deletionRequestTime field. It is set to the time you make the call.
I believe that is why you are seeing this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for clarification... I checked - you CAN set it in request, it'll simply be ignored (it seems)... in response that's returned back, this field is set to the time you make the call.... Alternatively, you can make a request without setting this field as well.. in SHORT: deletionRequestTime is *optional* parameter in request (without any affect how API behaves). Would be good if this could be clarified in the docs Correct me if I'm mistaken pls.

Answer (score 2):

First off i dont think your miss-interperting it I dont think the documentation is clear.

The following is from [userDeletionRequest](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/userdeletion/v3/reference/userDeletion/userDeletionRequest)

> deletionRequestTime    datetime
>
> This marks the point in time up to which all user data for the specified end user and Google Analytics property or Firebase project should be deleted.

Now to me that means that its a point in time that the data should be deleted. as in one day? one minute a time stamp?  would this then mean you will need to loop though every hour minute in a day to delete everything.

My current answer is this is confusing.  I am going to contact the team for clarification they are in West coast USA we wont get an answer back for several hours.   I will updated this when i know more.

**Clarification from Google**

> As per documentation, deletionRequestTime represents a timestamp **up to
> which all** use data will be deleted. In other words, all data from the
> beginning of time until the point returned in deletionRequestTime will
> be deleted.

Comment: Email sent i will post back tonight when i hear something.

Comment: Thanks a lot! btw I just tried API explorer, and it seems this parameter is NOT mandatory .. the request goes through without this parameter as well... Are you in API team ? I've few other API queries as well  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421634/ga-management-api-custom-dimensions-list-error-403-insufficient-permissio

Comment: I am a Google Developer expert for Google Analytics.  Big title comes without pay but means i have contact to the team and have been working with Google stuff for four years.  I will have a look at your other question

Comment: Thanks ! Do you mind sharing update? vibhorj [@] hotmail. I check the link / doc it’s still the same , I’ll wait until they update . Thanks for your efforts. Cheers!

Comment: @DalmTo would you mind taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064698/how-do-i-delete-user-analytics-data-from-firebase-using-userdeletionrequestsups)